# Convert from PointCloud to PCD

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I wanted to convert my point cloud (of type sensor_msgs::PointCloud2) published in a topic /X to pcd file. I used the builtin rosnode pointcloud_to_pcd (from the tuto http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#pointcloud_to_pcd ). What I typed was:


rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/X


I verified there are messages coming in the topic / X using rostopic echo.
However, at the end, I didn't get a .pcd file in the directory where I launched the rosnode. Do you guys have an idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230520/convert-from-pointcloud-to-pcd/) by [rosGSCOP](https://answers.ros.org/users/26364/rosgscop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-03-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-03-30**:
Where is `pcl_ros` outputs when doing this process? Can you write?

**Comment by [rosGSCOP](https://answers.ros.org/users/26364/rosgscop/) on 2016-03-30**:
Hi. Thank you.I don't quite understand your question. Normally, according to the tuto, pcl_ros will output the .pcd file in the directory where I launch this pcl_ros node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I just discovered the error I committed. Actually, although there 's message  (of type sensor_msgs::PointCloud2) coming into the topic /X, they contain no data(no coordinates x,y and z). That's why at the end of the pointcloud-to-pcd conversion, I got no .pcd file.

---

Originally posted by [rosGSCOP](https://answers.ros.org/users/26364/rosgscop/) with karma: 13 on 2016-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0